# ERROR: ERROR: syntax error at or near "account" LINE 12: $delete_$account language plpgsql;

Tags: postgresql

I create a function with postgresql version 14. Here is the code of my function:

```
create or replace function chat_expired() returns trigger as $delete_$account
begin 
timeout = 24*60*60;
delete from chat where current_timestamp - last.messages.createAt == timeout
return new;
end;
$delete_$account language plpgsql ;
EXECUTE PROCEDURE chat_expired()
```

However, when I run I get the error:

```
ERROR: ERROR: syntax error at or near "account" LINE 12: $delete_$account language plpgsql;
```

I tried to resolve by adding the double quotes on this line but nothing:

```
"$delete_$account" language plpgsql ;
```

Comment: `$delete_$account` should be `$delete_account$`. You did not declare the `timeout` variable. And the equals operator in SQL is `=`, not `==`.  You are also missing a `create trigger` declaration.

Comment: 5-10 minutes here [plpgsql trigger functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html) would prove useful. The docs are there for a reason.